# Convergence in distribution of a normally distributed random variable multiplied by another random variable

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Suppose $\hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is an estimate of $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^d$ where

$$\sqrt{n} (\hat{\beta} - \beta) \overset{d}{\rightarrow} N(0, \Sigma)$$

and $\hat{\alpha} \overset{p}{\rightarrow} \alpha,$ where $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\alpha$ are also $d$-dimensional. What's the asymptotic distribution of $\hat{\alpha} ^T\hat{\beta} \in \mathbb{R}$?

My attempt:

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}^T\hat{\beta}) &= \hat{\alpha}^T \sqrt{n}\hat{\beta}\\
&\overset{d}{\rightarrow} \alpha^TN(\beta, \Sigma)\\
& = N(\alpha^T\beta, \alpha^T\Sigma \alpha)
\end{align*}

The second line follows from Slutsky's theorem. Is the above correct?

Comment: What is the relationship between $\hat \alpha, \hat \beta$? Independence?

Comment: @AndrewZhang No, not necessarily

Comment: Are you asking about asymptotic normality of $\hat\alpha_n^T\hat\beta_n$? Otherwise, it looks like $\hat\alpha_n^T\hat\beta_n$ converges in distribution to $\alpha^T\beta$ as $n\to \infty$ for fixed $d$.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Right, asymptotic normality. Would you mind expanding on your comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally,
\begin{gather*}
 \{\hat{\alpha}_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\alpha, \hat{\beta}_n\stackrel{p}{\to} \beta\}\implies 
 \{\hat{\alpha}_n\hat{\beta}_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\alpha\beta\},\\
 \sqrt{n}\begin{pmatrix}
  \hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha\\ \hat{\beta}_n-\beta\\
 \end{pmatrix} \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\Sigma_1) \implies 
 \sqrt{n}[(\hat{\alpha}_n\pm \hat{\beta}_n)-(\alpha\pm\beta)] 
 \stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\sigma_2). 
\end{gather*}
Suppose
\begin{equation*}
 \hat{\alpha}_n\stackrel{p}{\to}\alpha\quad\text{and}\quad
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\Sigma), \quad \text{as $n\to\infty$}. \tag{2}
\end{equation*}
From (2) couldn't get $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}_n^\top\hat{\beta}_n-\alpha^\top\beta) 
\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\Sigma_1)$(because $\hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha=o_p(1) $).

Related this problem, there is following theorem in asymptotic statistics(cf. A.W. van der Vaart,  *Asymptotic Statistics*, Cambridge University Press 1998, **Theorem 2.7**, pp 10).

**Theorem 2.7** Let $X_n, X$ and $Y_n$ be random vectors. Then

(iv) if $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X$ and
$\|X_n-Y_n\|\stackrel{p}{\to}0$, then $Y_n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$;

(v) if $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to} X, Y_n\stackrel{p}{\to} c$ for a constant $c$, then $(X_n, Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}(X, c)$.

Since $(X_n, Y_n)\stackrel{d}{\to}(X, c)\implies X_nY_n \stackrel{d}{\to} cX $, from above results, if $\alpha$ is a constant(vector). we could get
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n}\hat{\alpha}^\top_n(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\stackrel{d}{\to}
 N(0,\alpha^{\top}\Sigma\alpha).\quad \text{as $n\to\infty$}. \tag{3}
\end{equation*}

Now, we direct prove (3).  From (2), $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)$ is stochastic bounded, i.e.,  $\forall\epsilon>0$, there exists a positive constant $C(\epsilon)$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \sup_n\mathsf{P}(\|\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\|\ge C(\epsilon))<\epsilon.\tag{4}
\end{equation*}
Hence
\begin{gather*}
 \sqrt{n}\hat{\alpha}^\top_n(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)=E_1+E_2,  \tag{5}\\
 E_1=\sqrt{n}\alpha^\top(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta), \qquad E_2=\sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}^\top_n-\alpha^\top)(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta).\\
 E_1\stackrel{d}{\to}
 N(0,\alpha^{\top}\Sigma\alpha),\quad \text{as $n\to\infty$}. \tag{6}
\end{gather*}

\begin{align*}
 &\mathsf{P}(|E_2|>\delta)\le \mathsf{P}\big(\|\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\|\ge C(\epsilon)\big)+ \mathsf{P}\Big(\|\hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha\|>\frac{\delta}{C(\epsilon)} \Big) \\
 &\le \epsilon+ \mathsf{P}\Big(\|\hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha\|>\frac{\delta}{C(\epsilon)} \Big)\\
 &\varlimsup_{n\to\infty}\mathsf{P}(|E_2|>\delta)\le \epsilon, \quad \forall \epsilon>0. \tag{7}   
\end{align*}
Letting $\epsilon\downarrow0 $ in (7),
\begin{equation*}
 E_2\stackrel{p}{\to} 0, \quad \text{as }n\to\infty. \tag{8}
\end{equation*}
From (6),(8)(also Theorem 2.7(iv)), (3) is true.

**Add a replication** on 2023-08-23. For your attempt:
\begin{align*}
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}^\top \hat{\beta}) &= \hat{\alpha}^\top \sqrt{n} \hat{\beta} \\
  & \to \alpha^\top N(\beta ,\Sigma)\\
  & = N(\alpha^\top \beta,\alpha^\top\Sigma\alpha ),
\end{align*}
the second line couldn't hold, because
\begin{equation*}
 \{\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\Sigma)\}
 \nRightarrow \{\sqrt{n}\hat{\beta}_n \stackrel{d}{\to} N(\beta,\Sigma)\}.
\end{equation*}

The other fact similar (3): For a constant(vector) $\alpha$, if
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha)\stackrel{p}{\to}0\quad\text{and}\quad
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)\stackrel{d}{\to} N(0,\Sigma), \quad \text{as $n\to\infty$}. \tag{9}
\end{equation*}
then
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}_n^\top\hat{\beta}_n-\alpha^\top\beta)
 \stackrel{d}{\to}N(0,\alpha^\top \Sigma\alpha ). \tag{10}
\end{equation*}
The proof of (10) use following equality,
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}^\top_n \hat{\beta}_n-\alpha^\top\beta)
 = \sqrt{n}\hat{\alpha}^\top_n(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta)+ \sqrt{n}(\hat{\alpha}_n-\alpha)^\top\beta,
\end{equation*}
then using (3) and (9) obtain (10).

Comment: What's the difference between $a_n$ and $\hat{a}_n$ in your notation?

Comment: Thank you point my clerical error, I correct  it.